# MySQL code for latest rows works only in Chrome not in Firefox

Tags: mysql, google-chrome, firefox

I add 9 rows to my database everyday...

I use this code to show the latest 9 rows of my MySQL database:

```html
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM weltnachrichten ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 9) sub ORDER BY id ASC";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
           
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                
                echo '<tr class="wnnews"><td valign="middle" align="center" width="60" style="border:none;"><img src="http://watergate.tv/img/wnnewsicon.png"></td><td style="font-size:16px !important; border:none;"><a href="http://watergate.tv/wn/weiterleitung.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" target="_blank">+++ ' . $row['titel'] . ' +++</a></td><td align="right" style="font-size:16px !important; border:none;">Leser: ' . $leseranzahl . '</td></tr>';
            }
```

When I use this script on chrome it works, but it doesn't when I use it on Firefox...

On Firefox it shows me the 9 rows from like 3 days ago.

Do you know why, and how I can fix it?

Thank you,
Till

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue

Answer (score 0):

I just realised, that the problem is somewhere else:

-I use this code in Wordpress and when I'm logged in into wordpress it shows me the latest 9 rows, but when I'm logged out it does not... (So I think nothing to do with Firefox or Chrome...)